# Cisco Switch - Telnet enable password

Tags: cisco

I would like to setup my cisco 3750 switch such that:

- I can connect via serial cable with no password, then can "en" with no password
- I can connect via telnet, and I am prompted for a password, then can "en" with no additional password

I have setup my vlan interface with an IP.

```
interfave vlan10
ip address 10.0.10.100 255.255.255.0
```

and I have this configuration

```
line con 0
line vty 0 4
privilege level 15
password xxxxx
login
transport input telnet
```

I can connect via telnet, I am prompted for a password, and the password is accepted an allows access.

When I enter enable mode, it states "no password set"

Comment: My eyes are bleeding for two reasons...wanting to "en" on an equipment without password and of course...telnet. At the very least use SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use telnet or ssh without an enable password. I don't think you can disable this security measure.

I suggest using SSH since it's easy to setup with user and pass on Cisco devices and a lot more secure

Answer (score 0):

two things:
1) as for your config

```
line vty 0 4
 privilege level 15
 password xxxxx
 login
  transport input telnet
```

you have already have privileged level 15 when you enter vty session. 
you dont need to enter

```
 # en
```

because you already have privileges you need.

2) as i know ( but it is a theory) you can not have "enable" without password prompt when you login via telnet